# Pyomo: coupling variables

Tags: python, optimization, valueerror, pyomo

I am try to decide on an optimal battery size for an electric bus, where the battery size needs enough capacity for the whole day but should be as light possible. I want to be able to define a set of batteries that can be chosen from. Is it possible in Pyomo to define a Variable that can only be integer values (--> yes) and let this variable define other variables?

I am getting this value error: 
`ValueError: Error retrieving component battery_power_outs[battery_choice]: The component has not been constructed.`

Is there a clean way to solve my problem? What concept in Pyomo should I be using?

I would be very grateful for any hints/avenues I should be following!

```
from pyomo.environ import *


m = AbstractModel()

# ====== Parameters ====== #

m.timesteps = Param()  # amount of timesteps -> 1440 (each minute of day)
m.amount_battery_choices = Param()  # 4 choices
# m.battery_choices = Set([1, 2, 3, 4])

m.time = RangeSet(1, m.timesteps)
m.battery_choices = RangeSet(1, m.amount_battery_choices)

m.battery_consumption = Param(m.time)  # consumption of driving fixed in [kWh/min/t]
m.electricity_price = Param(m.time)
m.depot_charging_allowed = Param(m.time)  # zero if bus is at depot, one if bus on route

m.vehicle_weight = Param()  # in [kg]
m.battery_weight_factor = Param()  # [t/kWh]
m.battery_capacities = Param(m.battery_choices)  # in [kWh]
m.battery_power_outs = Param(m.battery_choices)  # in [kW] per minute
m.battery_power_ins = Param(m.battery_choices)  # in [kW] per minute
m.battery_costs = Param(m.battery_choices)  # in [$]

m.upper_SOC_bound = Param()  # between 0 and 1
m.lower_SOC_bound = Param()  # between 0 and 1

# ====== Variables ====== #

# choose a battery (1-4)
m.battery_choice = Var(domain=PositiveIntegers, bounds=(1, 4))
# for each minute of day. Charging/discharging of battery: keep in max power out and max power in
m.battery_flow = Var(m.time, bounds=((-1)*m.battery_power_outs[m.battery_choice], m.battery_power_ins[m.battery_choice]))
# for each minute of day. Charge level of battery: keep between 15-85% of full capacity
m.battery_SOC = Var(m.time, bounds=(m.lower_SOC_bound*m.battery_capacities[m.battery_choice], m.upper_SOC_bound*m.battery_capacities[m.battery_choice]))
# for each minute of day. Charge flowing to battery while bus in depot
m.depot_charging = Var(m.time, bounds=(0, m.battery_power_ins[m.battery_choice]))

# ====== Constraints ====== #

# start battery at 85% capacity, Otherwise battery is SOC charge at previous timestep + battery flow
def maintain_SOC_bounds(m, t):
    if t == 1:
        return m.battery_SOC[t] == m.upper_SOC_bound*m.battery_capacities[m.battery_choice]  # fix battery to be at max capacity allowed at beginning
    else:
        return m.battery_SOC[t] == m.battery_SOC[t-1] + m.battery_flow[t]
m.SOC_bounds = Constraint(m.time, rule=maintain_SOC_bounds)

# recharge battery at final time to same level as start time
def fix_final_SOC(m):
    return m.battery_SOC[m.timesteps] == m.upper_SOC_bound*m.battery_capacities[m.battery_choice]
m.final_SOC = Constraint(rule=fix_final_SOC)

# depot charging is zero when bus is not at depot, otherwise must be in charge limit of battery
def fix_depot_charging(m, t):
    if m.depot_charging_allowed[t] == 1:
        return m.depot_charging[t] == 0
    else:
        return m.depot_charging[t] <= m.battery_power_ins[m.battery_choice]
m.depot_charging_rule = Constraint(m.time, rule=fix_depot_charging)

# battery consumption fixed while bus is on route (as function of weight which is function of battery size)
# otherwise if bus not in depot (depot_charging_allowed=1) battery flow is zero
# otherwise battery flow is same value as depot_charging
# else (shouldn't catch?) ???
def fix_battery_consumption(m, t):
    if m.battery_consumption[t] != 0:
        return m.battery_flow[t] == m.battery_consumption[t]*(m.vehicle_weight + m.battery_capacities[m.battery_choice]*m.battery_weight_factor)
    elif m.depot_charging_allowed[t] == 1:
        return m.battery_flow[t] == 0
    elif m.depot_charging_allowed[t] == 0:
        return m.battery_flow[t] == m.depot_charging[t]
    else:
        return 0 <= m.battery_flow[t] <= m.battery_power_ins[m.battery_choice]
m.battery_flow_rule = Constraint(m.time, rule=fix_battery_consumption)

# ====== Objective ====== #

# cost of battery + cost of electricity to charge back to full (different prices for different hours)
def optimiseCost(m):
    overall_cost = m.battery_costs[m.battery_choice]
    for t in m.time:
        overall_cost = overall_cost + m.depot_charging[t]*m.electricity_price[t]
    return overall_cost
m.obj_cost = Objective(rule=optimiseCost, sense=minimize)
```

EDIT: Approach this by coupling Variables using Constraints. E.g if Variable `battery_capacity == 50` then constrain `battery_power_out == 50`

Comment: A parameter that depends on a variable (during the solve) is not a parameter but a variable.

Comment: That is true. But how can I couple these variables, i.e the battery capacity variable defines charging/discharging rates etc. Should I couple these in Constraints, i.e if Variable battery capacity = X then Variable battery_charge_rate = Y?